# Adding curly braces to fat arrow function breaks it

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

Can anyone explain why this works:

```
filteredArray = contacts.filter(
  (contact: Contact) => contact.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
);
```

but this doesnt:

```
filteredArray = contacts.filter((contact: Contact) => {
  contact.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(term.toLocaleLowerCase());
});
```

I'm at a loss as to why simply adding curly braces here seems to break this.

Comment: @mbojko I think that was the wrong duplicate

Answer (score 3):

if you are using curly braces, then you have to use `return` keyword. A single line statement doesnot need curly braces:

```
filteredArray = contacts.filter((contact: Contact) => {
  return contact.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(term.toLocaleLowerCase());
});
```